# If $a$ is deficient-perfect, can $ab$ be deficient-perfect if $b > 1$, and $ab$ is odd?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, conjectures, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions

Let $\sigma(x)$ denote the *sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$.

The [deficiency](http://oeis.org/A033879) of $x$ is given by the formula
$$D(x)=2x-\sigma(x).$$

A number $y$ is said to be *deficient-perfect* if $D(y) \mid y$.

Note that a deficient-perfect number $z$ is automatically deficient (i.e., $z$ satisfies $D(z) \geq 1$).

Here is my question:

> If $a$ is deficient-perfect, can $ab$ be deficient-perfect if $b > 1$, and $ab$ is odd?

The reason for the condition $ab \equiv 1 \pmod 2$ is to exclude the [case](http://oeis.org/A271816)
$$(a_1,b_1)=\bigg(2^k,2^{k+1}+2^t-1\bigg),$$
where $2^{k+1}+2^t-1$ is an odd prime and $t \leq k$,
as well as the case
$$(a_2,b_2)=(2^r,2^s).$$

**MY ATTEMPT**

Let $ab$ be odd.  This implies that $a$ is odd and $b$ is odd.

Let $a$ be deficient-perfect, and suppose to the contrary that $ab$ is also deficient-perfect, where $b>1$.

Then we have the divisibility constraints
$$D(a) \mid a \iff a = (2a - \sigma(a))c$$
$$D(ab) \mid ab \iff ab = (2ab - \sigma(ab))d$$

Substituting the first equation into the variable $a$ in the $\text{LHS}$ of the second equation, we obtain
$$(2a - \sigma(a))bc = (2ab - \sigma(ab))d \iff 2abc - bc\sigma(a) = 2abd - d\sigma(ab)$$
$$\iff 2ab(c-d) = bc\sigma(a) - d\sigma(ab).$$

But
$$c - d = \frac{a}{D(a)} - \frac{ab}{D(ab)} = a\cdot\bigg(\frac{D(ab)-bD(a)}{D(a)D(ab)}\bigg) = a\cdot\bigg(\frac{2ab-\sigma(ab)-2ab+b\sigma(a)}{D(a)D(ab)}\bigg)$$
$$=a\cdot\bigg(\frac{-\sigma(ab)+b\sigma(a)}{D(a)D(ab)}\bigg)$$
which implies that $c - d \leq 0$ since
$$b\sigma(a) \leq \sigma(ab).$$

We therefore conclude that
$$2ab(c-d) = bc\sigma(a) - d\sigma(ab) \leq 0.$$

Alas, this is where I get stuck.

> *Postscript*: Note that
> $$\mathscr{D} = 9018009 = {3^2}\cdot{7^2}\cdot{{11}^2}\cdot{{13}^2}$$
> is the **lone** *odd deficient-perfect number* that we know of, to this day.

> So essentially, the question asks whether we could produce **another** *odd deficient-perfect number* from $\mathscr{D}$ (via multiplying $\mathscr{D}$ by $\mathscr{D'} > 1$), or if it could be proven that this is impossible.

Comment: Why is a "deficient-perfect" number automatically deficient? It doesn't seem to follow from the definition.

Comment: Note that "deficient-perfect" numbers are tabulated at http://oeis.org/A271816

Comment: Since $a$ and $ab$ are odd and deficient-perfect, then $a$ and $ab$ are squares.  (Note that this implies that $b$ is a square.)  In particular, both $D(a)$ and $D(ab)$ are odd.  It then follows that
$$d\sigma(ab)-bc\sigma(a) \equiv 0 \pmod 4,$$
which appears to lead nowhere.

Comment: If, in addition, we know that $\gcd(a,b)=1$, then we have
$$d\sigma(a)\sigma(b)-bc\sigma(a)=\sigma(a)\bigg(d\sigma(b)-bc\bigg) \equiv 0 \pmod 4,$$
which would imply that
$$d\sigma(b)-bc \equiv 0 \pmod 4,$$
since $\sigma(a) \equiv 1 \pmod 2$ follows from $a$ being a square.

Comment: Lastly, since $a \mid ab$ and $b > 1$, then $$I(a) < I(ab)$$ where $I(x)=\sigma(x)/x$ is the *abundancy index* of $x$.  This implies that
$$\frac{D(ab)}{ab}=\frac{2ab - \sigma(ab)}{ab}=2 - I(ab)<2 - I(a)=\frac{2a - \sigma(a)}{a}=\frac{D(a)}{a},$$
from which it follows that
$$\frac{a}{D(a)}=c<d=\frac{ab}{D(ab)}.$$

Comment: @GerryMyerson:  My apologies for the delayed revert, I missed your comments above.  To address your concern, if a number $n$ is deficient-perfect, then its deficiency $d = 2n - \sigma(n)$ divides the number $n$.  In other words, its [deficiency](http://oeis.org/A033879) is positive, which means that $n$ must be deficient.